# FileFormat error when exporting image from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

When exporting from GEE this error is being given "Unexpected arguments to function toDrive(): fileformat" The code is as follows
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b80da3ce9d776e3207121b6281b3d780

```
function mask2clouds (image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
            .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
}
var s2 = S2.filterBounds(table)
        .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01')
        .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 1))
        .map( mask2clouds)
        .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2'])
        .median()
        .clip(table)
print(s2)
var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
}
  

  var clip= s2.clip(table)
print(clip)
Map.addLayer(clip, visualization, 'RGB');
Map.centerObject(table,10);

Export.image.toDrive({
image:clip,
description: 'HC_S2_20',
fileformat: 'GeoTIFF',
scale: 10,
region: table
})
```

Comment: I just leave out the fileformat line entirely. As in: `...description: 'HC_S2_20', scale: 10,...`

Answer (score 1):

The property name is `fileFormat`, not `fileformat`. See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-todrive). Replace that and it should work. Your assets aren't shared, so I cannot check if there's something else wrong.